# App Center Page Approval

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know why my App Page would still be in submission after 3-4 weeks of being submitted?  What drives certain apps appearing in the app centre search?

My app has over 20,000 users but still does not show up over titles that have 10k users

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this sounds like a question for Facebook support.